# Is it possible to use AJAX POST data for the constructor values in a PHP class?

Tags: php, ajax, class, variables, constructor

I want to call a PHP class via AJAX to process some form data. Since when you instantiate a class in PHP you can pass in values to be used in the classes constructor I wondered if the same thing was possible via AJAX?

I'm currently using the POST method with a separate function in the class to detect the post values and then process them, but I could save time by pre-loading the values in the contructor if this is possible!

**Update: Code example**

```
class myAjaxClass {
    private $data;
    public function __construct($could, $this, $be, $post, $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
        ...etc...
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You call a PHP script from Ajax and you would like to change that script, so it will use the constructor of the class to pass some parameters, instead of creating the class and then using setters. Is that right? If this is the case there is nothing specific to Ajax. It only depends on your PHP classes.

Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AJAX You can call only some script, e.g. my_script.php, that will look like

```
<?php
$myAjaxClass = new MyAjaxClass($_POST['could'], $_POST['this'], $_POST['be'], $_POST['post'], ...);
var_dump($myAjaxClass);
?>
```

and within JS AJAX call You have to provide the data for post, e.g. with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post(
        "my_script.php",
        {could: "COULD", this: "THIS", be: "BE", ... },
        function(data) {
            alert(data); // data must be a string... when object, use data.property, when array, use data['index']
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that this was the case. I realise that there's little in it really, just referencing the $_POST directly instead, but I just thought it would be more elegant if I could 'instantiate' the class with variables as you would in PHP directly.

Comment: That is not possible as JS is just client-side language and do not know anything about PHP, that is server-side language... You just can pass variables over default HTTP protocol from JS to PHP and PHP also can only get variables from HTTP protocol (I mean POST or GET, maybe PUT?).Anyway, You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The post values are superglobals so you don't need to pass them to anything.  If your ajax request is calling the correct obj all you need do is use $_POST within the methods of that class...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to write a base Ajax handler class to prepare and load the POST data etc. I can then extend this with other classes for specific purposes such as 'AjaxLogin' and 'AjaxRegister'.

Here it is:

```
class Ajax {

    protected $data = array();
    protected $command; // Used to request a specific method.
    protected $count; // Counter for multi-page forms (Really needed?)

    /**
     * Response is the output array to be serialised using `json_encode()`
     * @var Boolean - Used to imply the success or failure of the AJAX function (i.e. form validation)
     * @var Array (optional) - An array of output / error messages [ Defined as: 'messages' => ... ]
     */
    protected $response = array('valid' => true); // Output to be serialised using 'json_encode()'

    public function __construct() {
        /* Redirect empty or insufficient POST data with 'Forbidden' response header (overwrite false) */
        if( !$_POST OR count($_POST) < 1 ) {
            header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], false, '403');
            exit();     
        }

        /* Session validation (if 'hash' sent) */
        if( isset($_POST['hash']) AND $_POST['hash'] != md5(session_id()) ) {
            header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], false, '403');
            exit();
        }

        $this->processRequest($_POST['data']);
    }

    protected function addMessage($message) {
        $this->response['valid'] = false;
        $this->response['messages'][] = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Unserialise AJAX data. Accepts data from either:
     * - jQuery.serialize()         [String]
     * - jQuery.serializeArray()    [Array of Objects]
     */
    private function unserializeData($data) {
        // -- from jQuery.serialize()
        if( is_string($data) ) {
            $array = explode('&', $data);
            foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                $string = preg_split('/=/', $value);
                $this->data[$string[0]] = $string[1];
            }
        }
        //  -- from jQuery.serializeArray()
        elseif( is_array($data) ) {
            $array = (array) $data;
            foreach($array as $element) {
                $this->data[$element['name']] = $element['value'];
            //  $this->addMessage($element['name'].' => '.$element['value']);
            }
        }
        else $this->addMessage('Unable to process your request, Please contact our Technical Support!');
    }

    // TODO: Use strip_tags or something for security??
    private function processRequest($data) {
        /* Process serialised data in to an Array */
        $this->unserializeData($data);

        /* Process additional POST data (if present) */
        if( isset($_POST['command']) ) $this->command = $_POST['command'];
        if( isset($_POST['count']) ) $this->count = $_POST['count'];
        // Add additional POST data processing here!!
    }
}
```

Feel free to use, modify, pass judgement etc. as you see fit, I hope this helps someone! ;)